# Subir proyecto de laravel a servidor PROPIO

Tags: laravel

Buenas a todos, mi problema es el siguiente, he comprado un host propio, en el cual no dispongo de ssh, y he subido mi proyecto completo a la raiz, con public, vendor, app y todo, he configurado el archivo index, pero me sale el mensaje de: Whoops, looks like something went wrong. cuando accedo a la carpeta public, y la verdad estoy un poco frustrado, porque todo lo que encuentro por internet es para subirlo a un host compartido, y no me ha servido de mucho la verdad, alguien que sepa como hacer esto? y que pueda explicarmelo paso a paso?

Mi url seria webapp.es/public(aqui esta todo lo de public sin mas, pero el log me dice que no puede encontrar la ruta correcta.

Gracias anticipado!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de laravel estas utilizando? modifica el archivo `.env` para que te muestre los errores o revisa el log del servidor  a ver que esta pasando, en muchos servidor la carpeta publicar por defecto tiene otro nombre ej. `public_html` si es necesario tendrás que renombrar la carpeta al nombre indicado

Comment: utilizo la version 5.2, y utilizo ovh.com como proveedor, ya modifique el archivo de index.php, y en el log he visto que efectivamente la ruta no apuntaba correctamente, pero la rediriji, y me sale en blanco, algo frustrante la verdad, porque en el log no me sale ningun error desde que cambie el archivo index, solo pagina en blando

Comment: En la 5.2, la verdad no lo he probado, pero en 5.4 adelante, basta con renombrar `public` con el nombre de la carpeta pública de servidor por defecto o copiar los archivos de public en dicha carpeta. Algún error debe de estar dando revisa bien.

Comment: Hice una prueba con un proyecto nuevo en Laravel 5.2 nuevo + Auth y basto con renombrar `public` a `public_html` que en mi caso es la carpeta publicar por defecto del hosting.

Answer (score -2):

De mi experiencia (soy Ingeniero en Sistemas y me dedico a desarrollar Sistemas/Aplicaciones en Laravel), puedo decir que Laravel no esta diseñado para utilizarse en un hosting compartido. Por supuesto, existen excepciones con algunas empresas proveedoras de hostings compartidos, en los que funciona muy bien, pero no dejan de ser excepciones, y siempre van a funcionar de manera limitada.

Por ejemplo, si se quiere utilizar la funcionalidad de tareas programadas (scheduler) que provee el framework, es necesario contar con una cuenta administrador (root) del servidor contratado, y en el caso de un hosting compartido, dicha cuenta no esta accesible.

Por otra parte, puedo ocurrir que se quieran ejecutar algunos comandos linux, como hacer un dump de la base de datos (mysqldump), al hacer click en un botón, por ejemplo. Pero, algunas empresas proveedoras de hostings, bloquean ciertas funciones php (como exec), en la configuración php.ini de sus hostings compartidos, por lo que los comandos linux, no se pueden ejecutar.

Otra facilidad que otorga Laravel, son una serie de comandos, que permiten gestionar el mantenimiento de la aplicación/sistema, de manera muy sencilla, y dichos comandos, requieren acceso SSH para ejecutarse.

Es muy complicado desplegar un proyecto de Laravel, en un hosting que no tenga acceso SSH, ya que es necesario correr algún comando básico, como limpieza de cache: `php artisan config:cache` o `php artisan cache:clear`, entre otros (cuando se trabaja localmente, se generan archivos de configuración que quedan en el cache, con urls referidas al entorno local. Pero cuando se ejecuta algún comando de los que mencioné anteriormente, dichos archivos de configuración se refrescan, y se actualizan las urls, tomando como referencia, el hosting al que se subió el proyecto).

Si no se quiere gastar tiempo y energías, mi recomendación es cambiar a un Vps o a un Cloud, y si es necesario utilizar un hosting compartido, asegurarse al menos de que tenga acceso SSH.

Saludos

Comment: Estoy totalmente en desacuerdo con esta respuesta, tengo varios proyectos laravel en servidores compartidos sin problema alguno y sin ssh. El no disponer de ssh no imposibilita el despliege solo lo condiciona.

Comment: Cuando se trabaja localmente, se generan algunos archivos en cache (por ejemplo de librerías), con las urls absolutas al equipo donde se esta trabajando. 
Si se sube el proyecto Laravel a un hosting vía ftp, es necesario actualizar dichas urls, para que queden direccionadas de acuerdo al hosting donde se desplegó (que en mi humilde opinión, es lo que esta pasando en este caso). Cómo haces para actualizar dichas urls sin SSH?

Comment: @Nicolas_Fuentes no se a que url absolutas te refieres, si se utilizan los helpers que laravel provee para tal fin estas son revsueltas en tiempo de compilación y no afecta para nada. En cuanto a la cache la puedes eliminar antes de hacer el despliege si es necesario, o incluso puedes crear una ruta/controlador para lanzar los comandos de artisan via web. La consola nos facilita la vida en muchos aspectos, pero no es requisito necesario para trabajar con laravel.

Comment: Pues he probado a cambiar el index.php y .env de las mil maneras posibles habidas y por haber, he probado en hostinger y en ovh como hostings proveedores y en ninguno de los 2 consigo visualizar nada mas que una pagina en blanco, lei aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156278/laravel-5-1-and-ovh-issue     que ovh no es compatible con laravel, cosa que me extraña pero bueno, supuestamente en hostinger he visto gente que ha sido capaz de subir su proyecto y la verdad no creo que sea tan complicado subir un proyecto de laravel, gracias por sus respuestas y siento la tardanza

Comment: Por nada! He revisado Hostinger, y vi que el servicio que ofrece de Hosting Premium, tiene la opción de acceso SSH, por si te interesa. Saludos